# Finding Maclaurin series of a given function

Tags: taylor-expansion

For function: 
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{x}{1+2x}
\end{align}
Can be written as:
\begin{align}
f(x)=x\bigg(\frac{1}{1+2x}\bigg)\tag{1}
\newline = x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n2^nx^n\tag{2} 
\newline = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n2^nx^{n+1} 
\end{align}

Can someone explain how to get from $(1)$ to $(2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the geometric series; let $u=-2x$ then

$\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n$

and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing but the geometric series. Recall that
$$1+r+r^2 + \cdots+ \text{ad infinitum} = \dfrac1{1-r}$$ for $\vert r \vert < 1$.
To put it the other way, we have
$$\dfrac1{1-r} = 1+r+r^2 + \cdots+ \text{ad infinitum} \tag{$\star$}$$ for $\vert r \vert <1$, the Taylor series of $\dfrac1{1-r}$ is given by $(\star)$. In your case, we have
$$\dfrac1{1+2x} = \dfrac1{1-(-2x)} = 1 +(-2x) + (-2x)^2 + \cdots + \text{ad infinitum} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-2x)^n$$ for $\vert -2x \vert < 1$, i.e., for $\vert x \vert < \dfrac12$.